# connecting 22.04 LTS to Active Directory: GSSAPI Error [...] (Server not found in Kerberos database)

Tags: 22.04, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I am trying to connect the Ubuntu computers of my department to our active directory which worked well for quiet some of them by now. However, currently I stuck with a computer that has recently been updated on 22.04 LTS (most of the others are still on 20.04 LTS). Apparently that one does not connect properly to the AD domain controller. Systemctl gives me the following error message for the sssd service:

```
sssd_be[3807]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)
```

I have experienced this error message with some of the other computers before, and usually it was related to DNS issues. However, in this case I cannot find any obvious DNS errors. My domain controller is also acting as the DNS server in my network. resolvectl outputs the domain controller's IP as the current DNS server. Also, I can ping the domain controller with its name and nslookup my.domain.controller gives output that looks reasonable to me.

I have carefully checked /var/log/sssd/sssd_my.domain.log and found the following suspicious lines:

```
(2023-11-14 17:14:17): [be[my.domain]] [get_server_status] (0x1000): [RID#149] Status of server 'my.domain.controller' is 'name resolved'
(2023-11-14 17:14:17): [be[my.domain]] [get_port_status] (0x1000): [RID#149] Port status of port 0 for server 'my.domain.controller' is 'not working'
(2023-11-14 17:14:17): [be[my.domain]] [get_port_status] (0x0080): [RID#149] SSSD is unable to complete the full connection request, this internal status does not necessarily indicate network port issues.
(2023-11-14 17:14:17): [be[my.domain]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0020): [RID#149] No available servers for service 'AD'
[...]
(2023-11-14 17:14:17): [be[my.domain]] [ad_subdomains_refresh_connect_done] (0x0080): [RID#149] No AD server is available, cannot get the subdomain list while offline
(2023-11-14 17:14:17): [be[my.domain]] [be_ptask_done] (0x0040): [RID#149] Task [Subdomains Refresh]: failed with [1432158212]: SSSD is offline
```

However, I did not get any error message when I joined the realm with "realm join -U ad_admin my.domain.controller and on the domain controller side I see that the computer apparently in deed has joined my realm. Concerning /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and /etc/krb5.conf I use the same settings than on the other computers where everything works fine, i.e.

```
cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

[sssd]
domains = my.domain
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/my.domain]
default_shell = /bin/bash
ad_server = my.domain.controller
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = MY.DOMAIN
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
ad_domain = my.domain
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = simple
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```

```
cat /etc/krb5.conf

[libdefaults] 

udp_preference_limit = 0
default_realm = MY.DOMAIN
rdns = false
```

Any ideas where the problem might be?